# Swift LayoutSubViews Order

Tags: swift, layoutsubviews

I have a view with 2 sub-views - collectionView and a custom view. I want to set an action to run after the 2 views have been laid out, but layouSubViews is running twice and I can't differentiate between the 2 instances, so my action is being called twice. How can I detect the instance that relates to the custom view only and trigger the action then?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `layoutIfNeeded` from outside and executing your action after that. `layoutIfNeeded` will internally call `layoutSubviews`, but by doing it outside you'll avoid being subject to whenever the system decides to call `layoutSubviews`.